# Javascript: dynamically add onkeypress event in ie

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I am trying to add an onkeypress event to a dynamically created `p` element. This works fine in Firefox, Opera, and Chrome, but not in IE.

My code:

```
function newParagraphAfter(elem)
{
 blockElemId++;
 newPara = document.createElement("p");
 newPara.id = 'block_' + blockElemId;
 newPara.innerHTML = "Edit Here!";
 elem.parentNode.insertBefore(newPara, elem.nextSibling);
 document.getElementById('block_' + blockElemId).contentEditable = 'true';
 document.getElementById('block_' + blockElemId).focus();
 document.getElementById('block_' + blockElemId).onkeypress = function(event){return editKeypress(this, event)};
 document.getElementById('block_' + blockElemId).onkeydown = function(event){return editKeydown(this, event)};
 document.getElementById('block_' + blockElemId).onblur = function(){deleteIfBlank(this);};
}
```

Adding the id works in all browsers, and adding innerHTML also works. A test, of changing the background colour (`document.getElementById('block_' + blockElemId).style.backgroundColor = "#666";` also worked in all browsers.

However, the lines adding onkeypress, onkeydown and onblur events, and also the `.focus()` line do not work in IE.

Thank you in advance for any help,

Nico

**UPDATE:**

I would prefer not to have to use jquery if it can be avoided, simply because I like to be able to modify all of the code in my projects, and not use any 3rd party libraries. I would also have to learn a completely new way of coding, which I would rather not do if it can be avoided.

The `contenteditable = 'true'` line works perfectly.

Comment: (Not an answer to your question, but *just* in case you don't know about it: this is easily done using things like jQuery.)

Comment: No script error (which would stop further processing) when `contentEditable  = 'true'` is executed? Maybe add a working example in JS Bin? -- http://jsbin.com

Comment: I would prefer not to use jquery for the reasons stated above. I added a working example at <a href="http://www.brokenmyriad.com/editor.php">www.brokenmyriad.com/editor.php</a>. I tried JSbin, but the code didn't work in any browser there.

Comment: Ok, good it is solved. (Final shameless plug: I am sure jQuery, MooTools, Ext JS, YUI, ..., take care of many more current *and future* cross-platform issues than you can think of...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this: http://jsbin.com/uhiyi

Works fine in IE 8...

Comment: Thankyou so much. Your answer helped me to find the problem in my code.

Comment: So basically the code from the question was all right, and the problem was elsewhere?